# Pseudosphere covered by upper half-plane

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces, curvature

Consider the (half) [pseudosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere) (with radius 1), which is the surface of revolution in $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by the tractrix parametrized by (for $t \geqslant 0$)
$$ t \mapsto (t -\operatorname{tanh} t, \operatorname{sech} t)~.$$

According to Wikipedia (see [pseudosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere)), this surface is covered by the region $\{y \geqslant 1\}$ of the upper half-plane, with covering map given explicitely by:
$$(x,y)\mapsto \big(v(\operatorname{arcosh} y)\cos x, v(\operatorname{arcosh} y) \sin x, u(\operatorname{arcosh} y)\big)$$
where $t \mapsto (u(t),v(t))$ is the arclength parametrization of the tractrix above.

Ok. So in particular, we should have
$$dX^2 + dY^2 + dZ^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}~,$$
right? Here I have denoted of course
$$X = v(\operatorname{arcosh} y)\cos x \qquad Y = v(\operatorname{arcosh} y) \sin x \qquad Z = u(\operatorname{arcosh} y)~.$$

But without even bothering to compute the arclength parametrization, isn't it the case that:
$$dX^2 + dY^2 + dZ^2 = \big(v(\operatorname{arcosh} y)\big)^2 \, dx^2 \, + \, \frac{\big(u'(\operatorname{arcosh} y))^2 + \big(v'(\operatorname{arcosh} y)\big)^2}{y^2-1}dy^2$$
so in particular already the coefficient of $dy^2$, namely $\dfrac{1}{y^2-1}$, seems to be wrong.

Am I going wrong somewhere, or is Wikipedia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}\DeclareMathOperator{\arcosh}{arcosh}$The term **arclength** parametrization in the Wikipedia link is out of place: If
$$
(u(t), v(t)) = (t - \tanh t, \sech t),
$$
then
$$
(u'(t), v'(t) = (1 - \sech^{2} t, \sech t \tanh t).
\tag{1}
$$
Since $\sech(\arcosh y) = 1/y$ and $\tanh(\arcosh y) = \sqrt{y^{2} - 1}/y$, (1) gives
$$
(u'(\arcosh y), v'(\arcosh y))
  = \left(\frac{y^{2} - 1}{y^{2}}, \frac{\sqrt{y^{2} - 1}}{y^{2}}\right),
\tag{2}
$$
and therefore
$$
u'(\arcosh y)^{2} + v'(\arcosh y)^{2}
  = \frac{(y^{2} - 1)^{2}}{y^{4}} + \frac{y^{2} - 1}{y^{4}}
  = \frac{y^{2} - 1}{y^{2}}.
\tag{3}
$$

The induced metric is therefore
$$
dX^{2} + dY^{2} + dZ^{2}
  = \frac{dx^{2}}{y^{2}} + \frac{u'(\arcosh y)^{2} + v'(\arcosh y)^{2}}{y^{2} - 1}\, dy^{2}
  =  \frac{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}{y^{2}}.
$$